# Corda 4.3 client rpc throw error when we use LinearStateQueryCriteria to query by linear id

Tags: spring-boot, corda

I am trying to invoke a get by linear id for a state from a springboot application using corda rpc client. cordapps are build using corda 4.3.

Below is the query i use:

```
QueryCriteria queryCriteria =
                new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, idList, status, contractStateTypes);
List<StateAndRef<DemoState>> stateAndRefs = cordaRPCOps.vaultQueryByCriteria(queryCriteria, stateType).getStates();
```

The query fails to retrive data and throws an exception as shown below, **but if i use Corda 4.1 rpc client the same query returns a correct result**.

Below is the exception shown in the corda node logs when using corda rpc 4.3:

```
[WARN ] 2020-04-28T15:35:12,118Z [Thread-964 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] rpc.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler -
 Inbound RPC failed [errorCode=1ctda0y, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.1/1ctda0y] {actor_id=user1, actor
_owning_identity=O=SBI, L=Panjim, C=IN, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=81afab50-486a-406d-9e17-bbbcfdf5aaed, in
vocation_timestamp=2020-04-28T15:35:12.117Z, origin=user1, session_id=472a8267-7035-4e58-be6f-7b762c82bf2b, session_timest
amp=2020-04-28T15:32:59.497Z}
java.io.NotSerializableException: Internal deserialization failure: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: java.util.Li
st<*> -> net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria$LinearStateQueryCriteria -> null
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.des(DeserializationInput.kt:106) ~[corda-serializati
on-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.DeserializationInput.deserialize(DeserializationInput.kt:119) ~[corda-ser
ialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.amqp.AbstractAMQPSerializationScheme.deserialize(AMQPSerializationScheme.kt:225) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:71) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:73) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:85) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:105) ~[corda-serialization-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.rpc.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:584) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.rpc.RPCServer.access$clientArtemisMessageHandler(RPCServer.kt:77) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.rpc.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:295) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.rpc.RPCServer$createRpcConsumer$1.invoke(RPCServer.kt:77) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.rpc.RPCServerKt$sam$org_apache_activemq_artemis_api_core_client_MessageHandler$0.onMessage(RPCServer.kt) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1002) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1125) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: java.util.List<*> -> net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria$LinearStateQueryCriteria -> null
```

Any pointers as to how we could get this running using corda rpc 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using CordaRPC 4.3 while your Corda node is running v4.1. In such cases, you need to provide the `minimumServerProtocolVersion` to `CordaRPCClientConfiguration`.

Here's a sample code:

```
CordaRPCClientConfiguration config = 
    new CordaRPCClientConfiguration(Duration.ofMinutes(3), 4);
CordaRPCOps rpcProxy = new CordaRPCClient(NetworkHostAndPort.parse("<host>:<port>"), config)
    .start(<username>, <password>).getProxy();
```

Note the part `CordaRPCClientConfiguration(Duration.ofMinutes(3), 4)`, "4" here is the `minimumServerProtocolVersion` supported which Corresponds to Corda 4.0.

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. As you mentioned it was related to the mismatch of the versions. We upgraded the corda nodes to run on 4.3 and which things were fine.